# Help with making subtitles

Tags: pronunciation, listening

I'm making subtitles to a video about sights of London...but there is a couple of moments in the video,when pronunciation is not very intelligible.

Please help me to figure out what is being said:

Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrJNIUp2izQ

> 0:50 - there's lots of shows,markets, ****** restaurants. The river
>   Thames and ***** Tate Galleries,and ****  is the London Eye
>
> 1:30 -"Duck tours" are amazing ****bus, then it turns into a bout.

Comment: Lots of folks around here feel that this sort of question is inappropriate for SE, since it is not of value to future visitors, so it's likely to be downvoted and closed. I suggest that you take future questions like this to the main ELL [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin)

Comment: My best guesses (the sound editing obscures some of the transitions) are *an' it's lots of restaurants* ...  *there are t' buskers. / Another good thing is the London Eye* ... *They're [a] sort of bus, then ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 0:50 - There's lots of shows, markets, lots and lots of restaurants. The river Thames and there are lots of buskers, Tate Galleries. Another good thing is the London Eye...
>
> 1:30 -"Duck tours" are amazing: the sort of bus, then it turns into a boat and you drive straight into the river Thames.